# How to verify a GPG file signature on Linux and Windows without connecting to the Internet?

Tags: authentication, gnupg, pgp, code-signing

Can you please hint me to the steps I need to verify a file's signature (*without connecting to the Internet*) on command line using GnuPG, when I have the required files ready:
-installation file (eg the .exe file) 
-the respective .asc signature file of that installer
-the respective PGP public key number of the developer:

1) For Windows - what are the lines to input in the command line?

2) For Linux - what are the lines to input in the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> 2) For Linux - what are the lines to input in the command line?

On Linux:

`gpg --verify file.asc file.exe`

You can also use a shorthand:

`gpg file.asc`

which will aks you which file is the signed file.

In the special case where the signature file is named exactly the same as the signed file, except with `.asc` appended, this will automatically guess that this is the file to be checked against the signature.

> 1) For Windows - what are the lines to input in the command line?

I believe the same commands as used for Linux should work on Windows, provided GPG is installed. I cannot be sure though and I currently lack the ability to check it. I hope this answers proves useful to You either way.